# Java Akka's ActorRef async issues

Tags: java, asynchronous, akka

I have started to use Akka to do async with concurrent program:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class TestAkka {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ActorSystem as1 = ActorSystem.create("actor1");
        ActorRef ar1 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class));
        System.out.println("Start to say hello!");
        ar1.tell("Bob", ActorRef.noSender());
        ar1.tell("John", ActorRef.noSender());
        System.out.println("Finish to say hello!");
    }

    public static class Hello extends UntypedActor {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
            if (message instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + message);
                Thread.sleep(10000);  // <--Sim the job take a short time
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I execute above program, the system must finish one by one (not concurrent):

```
ar1.tell("Bob", ActorRef.noSender());
ar1.tell("John", ActorRef.noSender());
```

So the result is:

```
Hello Bob
(Wait 5 seconds)
Hello John
(Wait 5 seconds)
```

I want to make them concurrent, how to handle it? I expect Akka should auto handle it:) Thanks for your idea!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Only one thread can be executing a given actor at any time.

Comment: Clarified question

Comment: @JosephStyons Please let them edit to clarify.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis acknowledged.  sorry for any confusion.  This one feels like a good question is buried in there somewhere..

Comment: @JosephStyons I mean, I assumed the same thing, but, when editing, we shouldn't make changes that potentially change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of Akka (and the actor model in general) is that within a single actor, everything happens sequentially. This has several advantages including that an actor can be lock-free when handling its own mutable state. Concurrency is achieved through having multiple actors running simultaneously.

Therefore if you create two `Hello` actors and send them each a message, they will process them concurrently. (assuming your akka execution context has enough Threads).

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class TestAkka {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ActorSystem as1 = ActorSystem.create("actor1");
        ActorRef ar1 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class));
        ActorRef ar2 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class));
        System.out.println("Start to say hello!");
        ar1.tell("Bob", ActorRef.noSender());
        ar2.tell("John", ActorRef.noSender());
        System.out.println("Finish to say hello!");
    }

    public static class Hello extends UntypedActor {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
            if (message instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + message);
                Thread.sleep(10000);  // <--Sim the job take a short time
            }
        }
    }
}
```