# Java Akka's ActorRef async with scheduled issues

Tags: java, asynchronous, akka, scheduled-tasks

According to the program from this link:
[Java Akka's ActorRef async issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558635/java-akkas-actorref-async-issues)

Is there any Akka native functions that I can use as a scheduling functions for `actor.tell`? I want to schedule every time interval to auto "tell".

*By the way, I do not choose Java's Executor as I do not want to waste OS resources.*

Sample code attached:

```
ActorSystem as1 = ActorSystem.create("actor1");
ActorRef ar1 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class), "ar1");
ActorRef ar2 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class), "ar2");
Router router = new Router(new RoundRobinRoutingLogic());
router = router.addRoutee(ar1);
router = router.addRoutee(ar2);
System.out.println("Start to say hello!");
router.route("Bob",ActorRef.noSender());
router.route("John",ActorRef.noSender());
System.out.println("Finish to say hello!”);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [section in the reference guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/java/howto.html#scheduling-periodic-messages) should be very helpful with this.
From within an actor, you can do something like:

```
FiniteDuration delay = FiniteDuration.create(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
FiniteDuration initialDelay = FiniteDuration.create(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
getContext().system().scheduler().schedule(initialDelay, delay, self(), message, getContext().dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

From outside an actor, you can do something like below if you have an `ActorRef ref`

```
FiniteDuration delay = FiniteDuration.create(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
FiniteDuration initialDelay = FiniteDuration.create(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(initialDelay, delay, self(), message, actorSystem.dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender())
```

Using a Router:

```
ActorSystem as1 = ActorSystem.create("actor1");
ActorRef ar1 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class), "ar1");
ActorRef ar2 = as1.actorOf(Props.create(Hello.class), "ar2");
List<String> routees = Arrays.asList(ar1, ar2);
ActorRef routerActorRef = as1.actorOf(new RoundRobinGroup(routees).props(), "router");
System.out.println("Start to say hello!");

FiniteDuration delay = FiniteDuration.create(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
FiniteDuration initialDelay = FiniteDuration.create(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
as1.scheduler().schedule(initialDelay, delay, routerActorRef, "Bob", as1.dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender())

as1.scheduler().schedule(initialDelay, delay, routerActorRef, "John", as1.dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender())

System.out.println("Finish to say hello!”);
```

Comment: I found that the official document has mentioned to use a router that included all actor as RoundRobin, but how to integrate with the router, sample code like below.

Comment: A router can be created as an actor so that in the scheduler you use the router actorRef instead of a ref to the individual routees. See additional example above which uses your example.

Comment: In fact, I am not so sure what you said, could you teach me in the code? may be I am stupid in Akka :).... Are you meaning getContext().system().scheduler() xxxxxxxxx ???

Comment: Please see the updated answer with an example using a group round robin router.